# Unable to start Hive on Mac with mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, hadoop, hive, metastore

I have some trouble upgrading my local development environment on macOS 10.12.3 to Hive with mySQL, as I used a local derby metastore before.

Whenever I start hive, I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1625)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.SpanReceiverHost.get(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getFs(Warehouse.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 28 more
```

Hive is in version 2.10, Hadoop in 2.7.3. namenode and datanode are up and so is mysql, including the correctly initialized metastore database.

Environment variables are set up as such:

```
➜  ~ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3
➜  ~ echo $HIVE_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7:/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.2.2:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/christian/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/bin
```

Normal HDFS operations work:

```
➜  ~ hdfs dfs -ls /
17/02/26 18:54:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
drwx-wx-wx   - christian supergroup          0 2017-02-26 14:15 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - christian supergroup          0 2017-02-26 14:13 /user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend this wasn't a question, but a KB/knowledge sharing post all along.

Turns out, my Hive installation had hadoop-commons-2.6.0 as lib:

```
➜  lib pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib
➜  lib ll | grep hadoop-common
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  admin   3.1M Sep  3 07:29 hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
```

But the method was added in 2.7.3, see [source](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.3/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost.java#L71).

Hence replacing that library worked. I don't know how I managed to get that in there.